# Android - Update a contact

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to update a contact of my phone book directly from my app. I'm able to add and delete the contacts but the update just does nothing!

After the insert or when I grab the contacts, I collect the CONTACT_ID (Aka _ID).

Here is my code for the update:

```
public void update(Relation r)
{
    Log.e("", ""+r.getBook_id());
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
    ops.add(builder.build());

    // Name
    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data._ID,  new String[]{String.valueOf(r.getBook_id())});
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, r.getFirstName()+ " " +r.getLastName());
    ops.add(builder.build());

    // Number
    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data._ID,  new String[]{String.valueOf(r.getBook_id())});
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, r.getNumber());
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK);
    ops.add(builder.build());

    // Picture
    try
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(r.getPhoto()));
        ByteArrayOutputStream image = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100, image);
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data._ID,  new String[]{String.valueOf(r.getBook_id())});
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, image.toByteArray());
        ops.add(builder.build());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Update
    try
    {
        context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`r.getBook_id()` gives me the _ID value of the current contact.
`r.getFirstName()` and `r.getLastName()` give me the name of the contact.
`r.getPhoto()` gives me his photo uri.
And finally `r.getNumber()` gives me his phone number.

The Log line gives me a correct value of _ID, I don't think the problem comes from here.
Did I do something wrong?

Thanks.

Regards.

V.

---

Whole source code:

```
/**
 * Uses the Contacts API to load contacts from the phonebook.
 * 
 */
public class ContactUtils
{
    static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
    };

    private Activity context;

    static final int CARD_LIMIT = 50;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @version 1.0
     * @since 2012-03-28
     * @param context Context of the running activity
    */
    public ContactUtils(Activity context)
    {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of all the contacts in the phonebook
     *
     * @version 1.0
     * @since 2012-03-28
     * @return Returns a list of all the contacts in the phonebook
    */
    public ArrayList<Relation> loadContacts()
    {
        String select = "((" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND (" + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " == 1))";
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
        context.startManagingCursor(c);

        ArrayList<Relation> cList = new ArrayList<Relation>();
        int a = 0;
        Relation relation;
        while (c.moveToNext() && a<CARD_LIMIT)
        {
            relation = new Relation();
            relation.setBook_id(new Integer(c.getString(0)).intValue());

            String[] name_splitted = c.getString(1).split(" ");
            relation.setFirstName(name_splitted[0]);
            if (name_splitted.length > 1) relation.setLastName(name_splitted[1]);

            ArrayList<String> numbers = getPhoneNumbers(c.getString(0));
            relation.setNumber(numbers.size() > 0 ? numbers.get(0) : "" );

            relation.setConcept("Any");
            relation.setPhoto(loadContactPhoto(c) == null ? "android.resource://com.orange.rd.kramer/drawable/default_photo" : loadContactPhoto(c));

            cList.add(relation);
            a++;
        }
        c.close();
        return cList;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an uri pointing to the contact's photo
     *
     * @version 1.0
     * @since 2012-03-28
     * @param cursor Cursor on a specific contact
     * @return Returns an uri pointing to the contact's photo
    */
    private String loadContactPhoto(Cursor cursor)
    {
        if (cursor.getString(5) != null)
        {
            Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, cursor.getInt(0));           
            return Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY).toString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of all phone numbers that belong to the given contact
     *
     * @version 1.0
     * @since 2012-03-28
     * @param id Id of the given contact
     * @return Returns a list of all phone numbers that belong to the given contact
    */
    private ArrayList<String> getPhoneNumbers(String id)
    {
        ArrayList<String> phones = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor pCur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
        while (pCur.moveToNext())
        {
            phones.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
        } 
        pCur.close();
        return(phones);
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the given relation into the stock phone book
     *
     * @version 1.0
     * @since 2012-03-28
     * @param r Relation to be added into the stock phone book
    */
    public void insert(Relation r)
    {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

        Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
        ops.add(builder.build());

        // Name
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, r.getFirstName().replace(" ", "-")+ " " +r.getLastName().replace(" ", "-"));
        ops.add(builder.build());

        // Number
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, r.getNumber());
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK);
        ops.add(builder.build());

        // Picture
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(r.getPhoto()));
            ByteArrayOutputStream image = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100, image);
            builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
            builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex);
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, image.toByteArray());
            ops.add(builder.build());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Add the new contact
        try
        {
            context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String select = "(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " == \"" +r.getFirstName().replace(" ", "-")+ " " +r.getLastName().replace(" ", "-")+ "\" )";
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
        context.startManagingCursor(c);

        if (c.moveToNext())
        {
            r.setBook_id(new Integer(c.getString(0)).intValue());
        }
        else
        {
            r.setBook_id(-1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the given relation in the stock phone book
     *
     * @version 1.0
     * @since 2012-03-28
     * @param r Relation to be updated in the stock phone book
    */
    public void update(Relation r)
    {
        Log.e("", ""+r.getBook_id());
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
        ops.add(builder.build());

        // Name
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data._ID,  new String[]{String.valueOf(r.getBook_id())});
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, r.getFirstName().replace(" ", "-")+ " " +r.getLastName().replace(" ", "-"));
        ops.add(builder.build());

        // Number
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data._ID,  new String[]{String.valueOf(r.getBook_id())});
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, r.getNumber());
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK);
        ops.add(builder.build());

        // Picture
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(r.getPhoto()));
            ByteArrayOutputStream image = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100, image);
            builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
            builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data._ID,  new String[]{String.valueOf(r.getBook_id())});
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, image.toByteArray());
            ops.add(builder.build());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Update
        try
        {
            context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes the given relation from the stock phone book
     *
     * @version 1.0
     * @since 2012-03-28
     * @param r Relation to be removed from the stock phone book
    */
    public void delete(Relation r)
    {
        Cursor pCur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{""+r.getBook_id()}, null);
        while (pCur.moveToNext())
        {
            String lookupKey = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
            context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Finally, I found how to update a contact, here is the code of the update method:

```
    public void update()
    {       
        int id = 1;
        String firstname = "Contact's first name";
        String lastname = "Last name";
        String number = "000 000 000";
        String photo_uri = "android.resource://com.my.package/drawable/default_photo";

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        // Name
        Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE});
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, lastname);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, firstname);
        ops.add(builder.build());

        // Number
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?"+ " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)});
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number);
        ops.add(builder.build());


        // Picture
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(photo_uri));
            ByteArrayOutputStream image = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100, image);

            builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
            builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE});
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, image.toByteArray());
            ops.add(builder.build());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Update
        try
        {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The field `id` is the raw contact id returned when you insert a new contact into the database. Here is the code to get this id:

```
    ContentProviderResult[] res;
    try
    {
        res = KramerApplication.getInstance().getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        if (res != null && res[0] != null)
        {
            String uri = res[0].uri.getPath().substring(14);
            r.setBook_id( new Integer(uri).intValue() );
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Check my first question if you want to know more about how to insert/delete a contact.

Comment: Thanks for ur code. Your code for image working almost. But the problem is after editing the image it update the image only in detailview picture(native contact) not in listview picture(native contact)

Comment: Thanks.
After spending whole day your code saved me. (Y)

Comment: In my case, this solution didn't work, I had to change `ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID` to `ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID` and also provide the `raw_id`

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this helps you, however I found a blog about the difference between contact_id and raw_contact_id:

http://android-contact-id-vs-raw-contact-id.blogspot.de/

In this blog he explains well how the contacts api works and if i understand it correctly you have to use the raw_contact_id to change your entry. So forget the contact_id for update and change your update so that the raw_contact_id entry is changed. I would roughly guess it would look something like this :

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
.withSelection(RawContacts._ID + "=?", new String[]{entertheraw_contact_id})
.withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Lost Symbol Characters")
.build());
getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

I hope this helps you a bit and thank you again for your help form before.

Comment: Well I've tried to use your source code but it doesn't work. I've switched back to my previous code which give me the RAW_CONTACT_ID. Then I've modified my SC with yours. But nothing happens...

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind, is that maybe use ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI) instead of ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI).
This could solve maybe the problem

Comment: The following code updates the contact'name but also his phone number :s `Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(r.getBook_id())});
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, r.getFirstName().replace(" ", "-")+ " " +r.getLastName().replace(" ", "-"));
        ops.add(builder.build());`

Comment: Thank you for posting the correct answer. When you update using the rawContact does the raw the contact_id change or stay the same? Can you update a rawContact wiht information it did not have before? I mean could you update the rawContact with an image, even if it did have one one insertion?

Comment: No problem. Yep the raw_contact_id and the contact_id stay the same. That's much easier when you store the id into a database. And yes, you can update a field that has not been previously filled.

Answer (score 0):

For Updating contact you need to have both **contactId** and **RawContact** id... so while updating add this also as a value in **where clause/selection args**..

something like this..

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        //------------------------------------------------------ Names

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PREFIX, data.getTitle())
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.SUFFIX, data.getSuffix())
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, data.getFirstName())
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME, data.getMiddleName())
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, data.getSuffix())
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, data.getFirstName()+" "+data.getMiddleName()).build());
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. When and where am I supposed to use that code? My phonebook is made of former contact entries (That the user did before installing the app) and entries that the app made. I'll edit my first post with the whole source code.