# Programmatically remove contact picture from Android

Tags: android-contacts

I am trying to remove a contact picture via code. I tried this by setting the Photo.PHOTO to null. However, the statement throws an exception. Here is the code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
int             result = 0;

values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId);
values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(Photo.PHOTO, (byte[])null);

result = getContext().getContentResolver().update(Data.CONTENT_URI, values, Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)});
```

and here is the exception

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
>       at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
>       at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
>       at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
>       at com.android.providers.contacts.DataRowHandler.getAugmentedValues(DataRowHandler.java:332)
>       at com.android.providers.contacts.DataRowHandlerForStructuredName.update(DataRowHandlerForStructuredName.java:70)
>       at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.updateData(ContactsProvider2.java:4507)
>       at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.updateData(ContactsProvider2.java:4490)
>       at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.updateInTransaction(ContactsProvider2.java:3875)
>       at com.android.providers.contacts.AbstractContactsProvider.update(AbstractContactsProvider.java:143)
>       at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.update(ContactsProvider2.java:2061)
>       at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.update(ContentProvider.java:235)
>       at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:990)

Answer (score 0):

here's how you can delete the photo (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9924883/878126)) :

```
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);

builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
        new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE });
builder.withValue(Integer.toString(id),ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, (byte[0])null);

final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(builder.build());
getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```