# Which unique key to update an Android contact

Tags: android

which is the right unique contact identifier for updating an Android contact?

- ContactsContract.Contacts._ID
- ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
- ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY
- ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907751/android-update-a-contact

Answer (score 0):

ContactsContract.Contacts._ID is the right and only unique id. It is referenced by the CONTACT_ID from other tables e. g. : ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID