# android Editing contact programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, contactscontract

I'm trying to edit contact details programmatically. I want to change the contact name having the phone number is equal to 123. Here is my Non working code.

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode("123"));

        // This query will return NAME and ID of contact, associated with phone //number.

        Cursor mcursor = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);

        //Now retrive _ID from query result
        long idPhone = 0;
        try {
            if (mcursor != null) {
                if (mcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    idPhone = Long.valueOf(mcursor.getString(mcursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID)));
                    String getID = String.valueOf(idPhone);
                    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), getID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Uri uri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,3625);
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,"After Changed name");
                    getContentResolver().update(uri, values, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID+"=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(idPhone)});

                }
            }
        } finally {
            mcursor.close();
        }
```

Currently I'm finding the phone number and getting the phone number's ID. With ID I'm trying to update it, seems it's not updating the phone number with ID.

Answer (score 0):

here is working code for me.

```
 public void updateContact (String contactId, String newNumber, Activity act) throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException{

    //ASSERT: @contactId alreay has a work phone number 
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(); 
    String selectPhone = Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='"  + 
                    Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND " + Phone.TYPE + "=?";
    String[] phoneArgs = new String[]{contactId, String.valueOf(Phone.TYPE_WORK)}; 
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs)
            .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)
            .build()); 
    act.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
}


 //hope this also work for you.
```

Comment: I have phone number already. I want to change the contact name from given phone number.

Comment: pass contact number as parameter in contactId

Comment: ok disha it works for me you can check github example here.  https://github.com/gwoodhouse/ContactContractSample/blob/master/ContactsIntegration/src/com/woodhouse/example/activity/ContactsIntegrationActivity.java

Comment: also you can check this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907751/android-update-a-contact

Comment: I didn't understand the difference between contact id and raw contact id. Can you please modify your code ? The link you gave me is hard to understand.

Comment: raw contact id returned when you insert a new contact into database and the you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907751/android-update-a-contact