# Updating a contact

Tags: java, android, contacts, android-contacts

I am trying to update a contact in android. While updating, multiple things might have happened. Like a number out of 2 numbers might have gotten deleted. 3 new numbers might have gotten added. An email address might have been added. And new photo might have been added.

What I was doing up till now was I deleted a contact's information from android database and inserted a new one. But I believe this is not a correct way to do it. This is very harmful when we successfully delete a contact but fail to add the new details.

This way whole contact gets deleted.

Is there any suggested way to update a contact.

Thanks

Comment: Note : Delete and insert will changed the ID meaning you could break some links.

Comment: Be Code Specific..!!

Comment: @AxelH : I am deleting the Phone numbers in the data table on the basis of contact id, so that seems to be fine. But, yes, I am running the risk of doing what you suggested. So not sure what to do here. Also, I cannot find a correct way to do this.

Comment: what you want to actually do ? you want to update a particular contact without deleting it from the contacts DB ?

Comment: @Roy : I doubt you need code to understand simple english. The explanation is simple enough to understand what problem I am facing.

Comment: @HasifSeyd : Yes, in plain words, I want to update a contact. This update is generic update meaning it might have multiple changes/addition/deletion info in that particular contact

Comment: @ShReYaNsH _I doubt you need code to understand simple english_ True, but we are not here to do your work so showing what you already have done is better to get an answer. We are not giong to start from scratch

Comment: @ShReYaNsH for multiple operations like deletion/addition/updation you can use contentProviderOperation onto that specific contact in DB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Update a contact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907751/android-update-a-contact) (first result from Google _android update contact_, please search before writing an answer)

Comment: @ShReYaNsH Stack Overflow is not here to start from the very scratch,U need to implement the code and and then if u face any error,here we are to resolve it based on the Logcat error trace..!!!

Comment: `While updating, multiple things might have happened.` you mean other apps might update the contact while your app is trying to update it?